# DPDK throws EAL: eal_memalloc_alloc_seg_bulk(): couldn't find suitable memseg_list on string concatenate

Tags: c, linux, dpdk

I have a DPDK environment setup and the buggy part of my program concatenates a string. That string can be as long as it gets (lets say a 1,000,000 max characters).
I run my program with **./program --lcores='0-4'**

I'm using DPDK's rte_malloc, rte_memcpy, rte_strlcat and rte_free functions. Below is a snippet of the code

```
int current_length = strlen(fx->var);
int new_length = (datalen + current_length) + 1;

char *temp = (char *)rte_malloc("char *", new_length * (*fx->var), 0);

rte_memcpy(temp, fx->var, current_length);
rte_strlcat(temp, data, datalen);
temp[new_length] = '\0';


fx->var = (char *)rte_malloc("var", new_length * (*fx->var), 0);
rte_memcpy(fx->var, temp, new_length);
fx->var[new_length] = '\0';

rte_free(temp);
```

My program exits after sometime with **EAL: eal_memalloc_alloc_seg_bulk(): couldn't find suitable memseg_list**. Following is the stack trace I'm getting

```
(gdb) where
#0  0x0000555555564d5b in _mm256_storeu_si256 (__A=..., __P=0x0) at /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/9/include/avxintrin.h:928
#1  rte_mov32 (
    src=0x1a80b5a80 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", dst=0x0) at /usr/local/include/rte_memcpy.h:320
#2  rte_mov64 (
    src=0x1a80b5a80 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", dst=0x0) at /usr/local/include/rte_memcpy.h:330
#3  rte_memcpy_aligned (n=88, src=0x1a80b5a80, dst=0x0) at /usr/local/include/rte_memcpy.h:856
#4  rte_memcpy (n=88, src=0x1a80b5a80, dst=0x0) at /usr/local/include/rte_memcpy.h:872
#5  parse_something (flow=0x7ff7c83c8288, id=60806, 
    data=0x7ff82cd77cc5 "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", datalen=89, flags=4) at main.c:1187
#6  0x000055555557c2e1 in process_something (result=0x7fffed7fad88) at main.c:2147
#7  0x000055555557c467 in some_flow (worker=0x7fffed7fad70, result=0x7fffed7fad88) at main.c:2199
#8  0x000055555557e5e0 in some_loop (arg=0x5555556262f0) at main.c:2273
```

I need an idea of whats going wrong here, am I missing some EAL configurations. Until then I'm looking into the docs and trying to understand from DPDK programmer's guide (EAL, Mbuf, Mempool library in specific).

Machine specs

- DPDK 20.11.0-rc1
- Ubuntu 20 (x86_64 GNU/Linux kernel 5.8.0-44-generic)
- CPU: 32
- RAM: 256GB
- 2 DPDK ports(igb_uio) 6-7 GB/s
- 1GB Hugepages

*Let me know if I've misssed something in the details above*

Comment: is not `(*fx->var)` a string and not integer. Can you try changing from string to int and post the result.

Comment: well (*fx->var) is a string, for each packet in a flow I have to append another char * to it. I believe my bug has something to do with **memseg_list**

Comment: `(char *)rte_malloc("char *", new_length * (*fx->var), 0);` should it be converted to `(char *)rte_malloc("char *", new_length * ato(*fx->var), 0);`. Where function atoi covnerts the string numerical representation to integer.

Comment: OH! I get it, it shouldn't be there at the first place, new_length is sufficient @VipinVarghese

Comment: thanks for understanding, if you find the explanation and code snippet useful accept and upvote, please.

Comment: Yeah no worries, Let me test it first @VipinVarghese

Comment: Request to accept is to close the ticket, else community will be spending time on a resolved issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, one has to give a numerical value for multiplication. Else ASCII value of `fx->var` will be used. Hence the suggestion in the comment is shared to use `atoi(fx->var)` for the numerical string to int value.

Note:By modifying the code snippet I am able to get it up and running, hence there is no issue in rte_malloc.

Modified Code:

```
#include <rte_eal.h>
#include <rte_memcpy.h>
#include <rte_string_fns.h>
#include <rte_malloc.h>

char *mystring = "test my string: ";
char *data = "My Data.. ";
int datalen = 10;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
        if (0 == rte_eal_init(argc, argv))
                rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "failed to init!");

        int current_length = strlen(mystring);
        int new_length = (datalen + current_length) + 1;

        //char *temp = (char *)rte_malloc("char *", new_length * (*mystring), 0);
        char *temp = (char *)rte_malloc("char *", new_length, 0);
        if (temp == NULL)
                rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "temp is null!");

        rte_strlcat(temp, mystring, current_length);
        rte_strlcat(temp + current_length - 1, data, datalen);
        temp[new_length] = '\0';

        mystring = (char *)rte_malloc("var", new_length * (*mystring), 0);
        if (mystring == NULL)
                rte_exit(EXIT_FAILURE, "mystring is null!");

        rte_memcpy(mystring, temp, new_length);
        mystring[new_length] = '\0';

        printf("(%s)!\n\n", mystring);
        rte_free(temp);

        printf("Done!");
```

Build command: `gcc /tmp/t.c $(pkg-config --cflags --libs --static libdpdk) -g`

Execution Command:  `sudo ./a.out --no-pci`

[Edit-1] updated with the test strings suggest by `Abid Zaidi`

Result: *(test my string:My Data..)!*

Comment: So after removing (*fx->var) (which was my honest mistake) I found out strlcat() isn't working as desired. instead using **snprintf(&temp[current_length], datalen, "%s", data);** did the trick

Comment: I don't have the data set you are using, for the dat set I n the cod esnippet it works. But happy to hear that snprintf was work around. Please accept or upvote to close the ticket.

Comment: Edited your answer with few lines, Accepting this as answer kindly approve my edit

Comment: @AbidZaidi as pointed out in my earlier comment rte_strlcat works for the data set explained in the snippet. can you share in a new ticket the specific strings which fails for rte_strlcat?

Comment: honestly idk whats wrong in rte_strlcat, it should have worked, copied its internal logic which is snprintf, I found it from here https://doc.dpdk.org/api/rte__string__fns_8h_source.html

Comment: rte_strlcat is created to avoid sys call overhead.